# Why did the error of the result of my ANN program only decreased a little while i was training it?

Tags: c++, machine-learning

I tried to train a 3-layer ANN with the function `xor`, but it doesn't work.
the input is 2 boolean number and the output is 2 number which represent the probability that the result is 1 or 0;

This is its variance at the beginning.

```
...
0 0
res: 0.24121 0.197543
variance: 0.35106
...
```

This is its variance after it has trained 10000 times.

```
...
1 1
res: 0.506383 0.476809
variance: 0.265076
...
```

Although the variance had decreased a little, but its result was wrong.

This is my code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#define sig(x) (1.0/(1/exp(x)+1))
using namespace std;
double rate=0.1;//training rate
const int MXF=10;//max number of layer
const int MXPF=20;//max num of node per layer

int fl,width[MXF];//num of layer,num of node on each floor
struct node{
    double w[MXPF],bias,net,out,del;
    inline void cal(){out=sig(net);}
    inline void prt(){
        cout<<net<<" "<<out<<" "<<del<<endl;
        for(int i=1;i<MXPF;i++)
            cout<<w[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}arr[MXF][MXPF];

inline void clr(){
    for(int i=1;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++)
            arr[i][j].net=arr[i][j].out=arr[i][j].del=0;
}
inline void init(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=1;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++){
            arr[i][j].bias=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
            for(int k=1;k<=width[i+1];k++)
                arr[i][j].w[k]=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        }
}
//calculate res
inline void calr(double *tarr){
    clr();
    for(int i=1;i<=width[1];i++)
        arr[1][i].net=tarr[i];
    for(int i=1;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++){
            arr[i][j].net+=arr[i][j].bias;
            arr[i][j].cal();
            for(int k=1;k<=width[i+1];k++)
                arr[i+1][k].net+=arr[i][j].out*arr[i][j].w[k];
        }
    cout<<"res: ";
    for(int i=1;i<=width[fl];i++)
        cout<<arr[fl][i].out<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

//calculate delta
inline void cald(double *tarr){
    double diff=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=width[fl];i++){
        diff+=0.5*(tarr[i]-arr[fl][i].out)*(tarr[i]-arr[fl][i].out);
        arr[fl][i].del=(tarr[i]-arr[fl][i].out)*(1-arr[fl][i].out)*arr[fl][i].out;
    }
    cout<<"variance: "<<diff<<endl;
    for(int i=fl-1;i;i--)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++)
            for(int k=1;k<=width[i+1];k++)
                arr[i][j].del+=arr[i][j].out*(1-arr[i][j].out)*arr[i][j].w[k]*arr[i+1][k].del;
}

//modify the weight
inline void modw(){
    for(int i=1;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++){
            arr[i][j].bias+=rate*arr[i][j].del;
            for(int k=1;k<=width[i+1];k++)
                arr[i][j].w[k]+=rate*arr[i][j].del*arr[i][j].net;
        }
}

double x[3],y[3];

int main(){
    fl=3;
    width[1]=width[3]=2;
    width[2]=4;
    
    init();
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
        int a,b;
        a=rand()&1;
        b=rand()&1;
        x[1]=a;
        x[2]=b;
        if(a^b)y[1]=1,y[2]=0;
        else y[1]=0,y[2]=1;
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
        calr(x);
        cald(y);
        modw();
    }
    //for(int i=1;i<=width[fl];i++)cout<<arr[fl][i].out;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Profiling all of this code would be quite difficult, especially for someone who didn't write it. I suggest stating what you have tried so far. Particularly, I suggest trying: 1) to adjust the learning rate (try it with various powers of 10, for instance), 2) to adjust the number of layers and nodes (1 hidden layer with just a few nodes is sufficient for XOR; you can find proofs of this), 3) to unit test your loss function and gradient computations, and 4) to try anything else you can think of. If you find the answer to your question, feel free to answer it yourself. Otherwise, let us know.

Comment: Just curious. What is the reason that your `for` loops that iterate indices into your arrays start with `1` instead of `0`? That is, why (e.g.) `for (int i = 1; i <= fl; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < fl; ++i)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just fixed it, there are few problems in my code.

1. I updated `w[i,j]` in the wrong way

The wrong one is:

```cpp
w[i,j] <- w[i,j]+ trainingrate * delta[i] * net[i,j]
```

However the correct way is:

```cpp
w[i,j] <= w[i,j]+ trainingrate * delta[j] * net[i,j]
```

2. The learning rate should be bigger (thanks to Alexander Guyer 's advise), I changed it to 10

Its loss curve was like(sorry but I don't know how to visualize it):

| training times | loss |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0.094699458739 |
| 2000 | 0.068095601434 |
| 3000 | 0.066106646618 |
| 4000 | 0.065386921266 |
| 5000 | 0.064941943256 |
| 6000 | 0.000821173199 |
| 7000 | 0.000000012326 |
| 8000 | 0.000000012311 |
| 9000 | 0.000000012295 |
| 10000 | 0.000000012280 |

This is the final version of my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#define sig(x) (1.0/(exp(-(x))+1))
using namespace std;
double rate=10;
const int MXF=10;
const int MXPF=20;
const int MXD=20;

int fl,width[MXF];
struct node{double w[MXPF],net,out,del;}arr[MXF][MXPF];

void init(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=1;i<=fl;i++){
        arr[i][0].out=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++)
            for(int k=0;k<=width[i-1];k++)
                arr[i][j].w[k]=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX/10;
    }
}
void prtres(){
    cout<<"Res: ";
    for(int i=1;i<=width[fl];i++)
        cout<<arr[fl][i].out<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
void prtall(){
    for(int i=1;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++){
            cout<<i<<","<<j<<":\n";
            cout<<arr[i][j].net<<" "<<arr[i][j].out<<" "<<arr[i][j].del<<endl;
            for(int k=0;k<=width[i-1];k++)
                cout<<arr[i][j].w[k]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
}
void calr(double ina[MXPF]){
    for(int i=1;i<=width[1];i++){
        arr[1][i].net=ina[i];
        arr[1][i].out=sig(arr[1][i].net);
    }
    for(int i=2;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++){
            arr[i][j].net=0;
            for(int k=0;k<=width[i-1];k++)
                arr[i][j].net+=arr[i][j].w[k]*arr[i-1][k].out;
            arr[i][j].out=sig(arr[i][j].net);
        }
}

double cald(double outa[MXPF]){
    double res=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=width[fl];i++){
        res+=(outa[i]-arr[fl][i].out)*(outa[i]-arr[fl][i].out);
        arr[fl][i].del=(outa[i]-arr[fl][i].out)*arr[fl][i].out*(1-arr[fl][i].out);
    }
    for(int i=fl-1;i;i--)
        for(int j=0;j<=width[i];j++){
            arr[i][j].del=0;
            for(int k=1;k<=width[i+1];k++)
                arr[i][j].del+=arr[i][j].out*(1-arr[i][j].out)*arr[i+1][k].w[j]*arr[i+1][k].del;
        }
    return res/2;
}

void modw(){
    for(int i=2;i<=fl;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=width[i];j++)
            for(int k=0;k<=width[i-1];k++)
                arr[i][j].w[k]+=rate*arr[i][j].del*arr[i-1][k].out;
}

void train(int traint,int datasz,double ina[MXD][MXPF],double outa[MXD][MXPF]){
    for(int t=1;t<=traint;t++){
        double diff=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=datasz;i++){
            calr(ina[i]);
            diff+=cald(outa[i]);
            modw();
        }
        if(!(t%1000))printf("%6d: %.12f\n",t,diff);
    }
}


double x[MXD][MXPF]={
    {},
    {0,1,1},
    {0,0,0},
    {0,1,0},
    {0,0,1},
};
double y[MXD][MXPF]={
    {},
    {0,sig(1),sig(0)},
    {0,sig(1),sig(0)},
    {0,sig(0),sig(1)},
    {0,sig(0),sig(1)},
};
int main(){
    fl=3;
    width[1]=width[3]=2;
    width[2]=3;
    init();

    train(10000,4,x,y);

    puts("---");
    calr(x[1]);
    prtres();
    calr(x[2]);
    prtres();
    calr(x[3]);
    prtres();
    calr(x[4]);
    prtres();
    return 0;
}
```